# Convert error method in jQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code part written by my friend using jQuery in a project and I am trying to convert this to pure javascript so I can remove the jQuery file. I specially do not understand the `.error()` part. I have a very limited knowledge with Javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function tripDestination(t, e) {
    var n = Math.floor(0x10000000000000000 * Math.random()).toString(36);
    n = t + "my?x=" + n, imageCell.empty(), imageCell.html("<img id='myImage' style='display: none'>");
    var a = $("#myImage");
    a.error(e), a.attr("src", n)
}
```

Comment: what is imageCell ?

Comment: It is a small app that was written to ping some websites using javascript. Similar to the concept of this. https://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = $("#myImage");
    a.error(e), a.attr("src", n)
```

The .error(e)  is the function that should handle the error.  e is passed into the tripDestination function.

Again with a.attr("src", n )   , it's assigning what's in n to the src attribute of the class "myImage"

I'm assuming there's a img tag `<img class="myImage">`  .

The javascript version of changing the src attribute is:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "hackanm.gif";
```

you can do this to your `<img>` tag :  `<img id="myImage">`

Regarding error handling for this:

```
var imgele = document.getElementById("myImage");

imgele.onerror = function(e){
  // console.log()
}; 

imgele.src = 'newimage.jpg';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your jQuery into pure `JS` like below.

```
var a = document.getElementById("#myImage");
a.onerror = function(e){
  //display error
}; 
a.setAttribute("src", n)
```